# Python logging setup for multiple child log files while disabling main log

Tags: python, logging

I have a few related but separate Python scripts that both make use of two internal modules that use logging.

The first script works fine using the root logger, and captures logging statements from the two modules. With the second script, however, I want to have a main log, but when it iterates over a list of servers, to send the logs to a per-machine log file, while suspending logging to the main log file and console. I have a hacky solution at the moment, which I'll show below.

```
import logging

DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s"
DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO

def get_log_file_handler(filename, level=None, log_format=None):
  file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=filename, encoding="utf-8", mode="w")
  file_handler.setLevel(level or DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)
  file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(log_format or DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT))

  return file_handler

def process(server):
  server_file_handler = get_log_file_handler("%s.log" % server.name)
  root_logger = logging.getLogger()

  # This works, but is hacky
  main_handlers = list(root_logger.handlers) # copy list of root log handlers
  root_logger.handlers = [] # empty the list on the root logger

  root_logger.addHandler(server_file_handler)

  try:
    # do some stuff with the server
    logging.info("This should show up only in the server-specific log file.")
  finally:
    root_logger.removeHandler(server_file_handler)

    # Add handlers back in
    for handler in main_handlers:
      root_logger.addHandler(handler)

def main():
  logging.basicConfig(level=DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)

  logging.getLogger().addHandler(get_log_file_handler("main.log"))

  servers = [] # retrieved from another function, just here for iteration

  logging.info("This should show up in the console and main.log.")

  for server in servers:
    process(server)

  logging.info("This should show up in the console and main.log again.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I'm looking for a less-hacky way to do this. I realize that just calling logging.info() and similar is a problem, and have changed the code in the two modules to use:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("moduleA")
```

and

```
logger = logging.getLogger("moduleB")
```

So the main script, be it scriptA.py or scriptB.py, using the root logger, will get the events from those two modules propagated and logged to main.log. A few other solutions I've tried are using a Filter on all the existing handlers that'd ignore everything from "moduleA" and "moduleB".

My next thought is to create a new named logger for the individual servers with the server_file_handler as the sole handler for them, and add that as a handler for the two module loggers as well, and remove those handlers at the end of process(). Then I could set the root logger's level to WARNING, so all INFO/DEBUG statements from the two modules would only go to the server-specific logger.

I can't exactly use hierarchical logger naming, unless that supported wildcards somehow, since I'd wind up with:

```
logging.getLogger("org.company") # main logger for script
logging.getLogger("org.company.serverA") 
logging.getLogger("org.company.serverB")
logging.getLogger("org.company.moduleA")
logging.getLogger("org.company.moduleB")
```

Logging from the two modules would only propagate up to the main logger, but not the two server logs.

It's basically a they-expect-a-tree, I-need-a-graph problem. Has anyone done anything like this before, and what's the most Pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Can you show the logger definitions in the two scripts?

Comment: @stderr: It's in the question already. They just use logger = logging.getLogger(moduleName) and get the rest of the log config from the main script.

Comment: I guess I'm curious how they get their confit from the main script then.  Regardless, hopefully my answer helps.

Comment: @stderr: The basic config comes from logging.basicConfig(level=DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL) in the main script, which affects everything in the logging tree. In the real scripts, I have a --debug command line parameter which changes the actual log level from INFO to DEBUG if set. I'll give your solution a shot at work this morning and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem.  My first instinct was to use `logger.getChild` but the default implementation won't do what you want.  Assuming you could dynamically add handlers to a single logger, it still wouldn't do what you want as you'd have to add filters to both the main file handler and to the server handlers to filter messages that shouldn't go into the server logs and vice versus.

That said, the good news is that a custom logger that creates a handler for each child is actually pretty easy and can be accomplished with a simple subclass modifying `getChild` and not much else.

The big changes below are just the `HandlerPerChildLogger`, `Logger` which differs from a normal `Logger` in that it requires two arguments rather than just the one `name` parameter.

```
import logging

DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s"
DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO

class HandlerPerChildLogger(logging.Logger):
    selector = "server"

    def __init__(self, name, handler_factory, level=logging.NOTSET):
        super(HandlerPerChildLogger, self).__init__(name, level=level)
        self.handler_factory = handler_factory

    def getChild(self, suffix):
        logger = super(HandlerPerChildLogger, self).getChild(suffix)
        if not logger.handlers:
            logger.addHandler(self.handler_factory(logger.name))
            logger.setLevel(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)
        return logger

def file_handler_factory(name):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="{}.log".format(name), encoding="utf-8", mode="a")
    formatter = logging.Formatter(DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    return handler

logger = HandlerPerChildLogger("my.company", file_handler_factory)
logger.setLevel(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename="my.company.log", encoding="utf-8", mode="a")
ch.setLevel(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)
fh.setLevel(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)
formatter = logging.Formatter(DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

def process(server):
    server_logger = logger.getChild(server)
    server_logger.info("This should show up only in the server-specific log file for %s", server)
    server_logger.info("another log message for %s", server)

def main():
    # servers list retrieved from another function, just here for iteration
    servers = ["server1", "server2", "server3"]

    logger.info("This should show up in the console and main.log.")

    for server in servers:
        process(server)

    logger.info("This should show up in the console and main.log again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It would perhaps be slightly tidier to leave the handler for `main.log` in place, but just change its level to a high enough value to prevent it outputting anything (e.g. `logging.CRITICAL + 1`) before the `server in servers` loop, and restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use logger naming and propogation

If your modules used a logger named `org.company.moduleX` then you could just add your file handler to a logger named `org.company` and block propogation up to your root logger handlers using [Logger.propogate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate)

Implementing it as a context manager to make it nice.

```
import contextlib

log = logging.getLogger("org.company.scriptB")

@contextlib.contextmanager
def block_and_divert_logging(logger, new_handler):
    logger.propagate = False
    logger.addHandler(new_handler)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logger.propogate = True
        logger.removeHandler(new_handler)

def process(server):
    server_file_handler = get_log_file_handler("%s.log" % server.name)
    logger_block = logging.getLogger("org.company")

    with block_and_divert_logging(logger_block, server_file_handler):
        # do some stuff with the server
        log.info("This should show up only in the server-specific log file.")
```

This will stop any messages from loggers at or below `org.company` from reaching the root logger handlers. Instead they will be handled by your file handler.

However this does mean that any loggers that aren't named like `org.company.something` will still reach the root loggers.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably similar to what I'll wind up doing. My problem was I didn't want to call both main scripts org.company, but as I'm not going to be displaying the logger name in the output, it shouldn't matter. If I had them as org.company.scriptA and org.company.scriptB, then they wouldn't catch org.company.ModuleX unless I could name it org.company.*.ModuleX.

Comment: You can still call your main scripts' loggers org.company.scriptA or B. But you add your main logging handlers to the root logger (say with logging.basicConfig) and block at org.company when you need to. I have tweaked the above answer slightly to maybe illustrate this a bit better.